# Html.RenderAction not using my routeValue parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm calling a RenderAction but my PartialViewResult is not receiving my sent parameter.

Here's my Default Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Here's my Call:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("InvestmentGroupDropDown", "TPAs", new { level = Model.InvestmentGroup });}
```

Here's my Action:

```
 public PartialViewResult InvestmentGroupDropDown(Guid? selectedId)
        {
        }
```

I  reach my Action no problem but the value I'm trying to send from my Model. Is not there when I reach my Action. I can see the value in debug mode plain as day in the RenderActions parameter. Why does it seem to be ignoring my parameter?

I should be getting a Guid in my PartialViewResult, instead i'm getting null.

Comment: If selectedId is the name of the parameter on the controller, you need to use the same parameter name in the view. Your RenderAction uses level.

Comment: Tieson, thank you. This was in fact the problem.

May I ask why the signature parameter name matters? I'm not a super expert on MVC but I figure if the parameter was being sent it would be what ends up on the other end.

I guess my best guess is I'm basically setting the ID of the parameter the route is expecting and if that's the case this makes total sense that they would need to be the same. Again thank you so much.

Comment: There's no magic involved. The framework simply matches any parameters sent with a request to those defined in the action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tieson T. provided me with an answer! Thank you!

I didn't realise the object name mattered here but it does. I changed level to the parameter name of my Action 'selectedId' and voila we have cookies!

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("InvestmentGroupDropDown", "TPAs", new { **level** = Model.InvestmentGroup });}
```

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("InvestmentGroupDropDown", "TPAs", new { **selectedId** = Model.InvestmentGroup });}
```